# Activerecord conditions and named scope - undefined method `created_at'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Subscriber  
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills. 

Skill   
has_many :positions
```

in subscriber.rb:

```
scope :notify_today, 
      includes(:skills => :positions).
      where("positions.created_at > ? AND positions.created_at > ?", 
             1.day.ago, self.created_at)
```

Basically I want to find all subscribers that have positions 1) created 1.day.ago AND 2) created after the subscriber

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because the class of `self` here is `Class`, not `Subscriber`, as is wanted.

As a solution, you can make a lamda like this and pass in the parameter for `created_at`:
(I presume your scope is working otherwise, because I have not tested this with *your* scope code specifically)

```
scope :notify_today, 
      lambda { |created_at| includes(:skills => :positions).
      where("positions.created_at > ? AND positions.created_at > ?", 
             1.day.ago, created_at) }
```

And use it:

```
@subscribers = notify_today(Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks Zabba. It was very educational. There is a message now "warning: multiple values for a block parameter" for the second line. Should I ignore it?

Comment: Not sure, but that could be happening if you have defined params for the lambda and either are not using it in the scope or are not passing a param where the scope is being called from.

Comment: Actually my problem was not solveed. Basically I want to find all subscribers that have positions 1) created 1.day.ago AND 2) created after the subscriber

Comment: Pass in the appropriate value for the created_at and check also by running the generated SQL whether it is indeed correct.