# Help me with scopes and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model:

```
Subscriber  
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

Skill
has_many :positions

Position
belongs_to :skill
```

I want to find all subscribers that have positions which...
  1. are created during last day
  2. are created after the subscriber was created

First condition is easy (*subscriber.rb*):

```
 scope :notify_today, 
 includes(:skills => :positions).where('positions.created_at > ?', 1.day.ago)
```

For the second condition [it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906229/activerecord-conditions-and-named-scope-undefined-method-created-at) to use lambda, but I didn't quite get it - I'm a newbie...

I'm using the scope in a *cron.rake* file to send email notifications to subscribers:

```
Subscriber.notify_today.each {|subsc| UserMailer.delay.new_positions_mail(subsc)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :notify_today, lambda {
  joins(:skills => :positions).
  where('positions.created_at > subscribers.created_at').
  where('positions.created_at > ?', 1.day.ago)
}
```

Note that `joins` is for searching on associated records, while `includes` is for eager-loading associated records.

Comment: Great! :) This is so simple. Thank you. I just had to change "created_at" to "subscribers.created_at", because there was a message "ambiguous column name".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added your fix into my answer in case anyone else has the same type of question.